# Append values to a list of json objects

Tags: python, json, list

I'm collecting weather data and trying to create a list that has the latest (temperature) value by minute.

I want to add them to a list, and if the list does not contains the "minute index" it should at it as a new element in the list. So the list always keeps the latest temperature value per minute:

```
def AddValue(arr, value):
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

    for v in arr['values']:
        try:
            e = v[timestamp]     # will trigger the try/catch if not there
            v[timestamp] = value
        except KeyError:
            v.append({ timestamp: value })

history = [
    { 'values': [ {'2017-12-22 10:20': 1}, {'2017-12-22 10:21': 2}, {'2017-12-22 10:22': 3} ] },
]

AddValue(history, 99)
```

However, I'm getting

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'**
```

Comment: What's the point of a dictionary if you have to iterate over it? Also, you're creating a timestamp on the fly. What are the odds that the Key _already_ exists?

Comment: I don't get why you want to trigger the except if the key is not there.

Comment: Furthermore I don't see what this has to do with JSON.

Comment: for v in arr['values']: don't think it works because your history is list..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You associate a *key* `k` with a *value* `v` in a dictionary `d` with:

```
d[k] = v
```

this works regardless whether there is already a key `k` present in the dictioanry. In case that happens, the value is "overwritten". We can thus rewrite the `for` loop to:

```
for v in arr['values']:
    v[timestamp] = value
```

In case you want to update a dictionary with several keys, you can use `.update` and pass a dictionary object, or named parameters as keys (and the corresponding values as value). So we can write it as:

```
for v in arr['values']:
    v.update({timestamp: value})
```

which is semantically the same, but will require more computational effort.

Nevertheless since you need to iterate over a dictionary, you perhaps should reconsider the way you structured the data.